# Specifying pixel depth in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, digital-image-processing

I have a simple model that calculates the NDVI from bands 3 and 4 of a raster dataset.  The input bands are 8-bit unsigned, whereas the default output NDVI is signed 32 bit.

How can I specify the pixel depth for the output NDVI as 8 bit unsigned?

[image]

Comment: Can this be controlled with an environment setting?

Comment: I haven't found a way to specify the pixel depth in the environment settings.

Comment: Does the calculator exhibit behavior that changes the pixel depth?

Comment: No as this is part of a model so I need to keep the image with the original 8 bit, do the calculations, convert it into 32bit and do some other calculations and then output it. The problem is to keep it at 8 bit for the first set of calcs.

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include this clarification to it, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result from NDVI will be continuous (i.e. decimal) values between -1 to +1, therefore the raster must be able to store these values, and will use signed pixel depth. If you truly want 8-bit unsigned, you will need to adjust the expression in the raster calculator by linearly scaling to values between 0-255 and then applying the int() function on the entire calculation. However, this still does not guarantee that the output will be 8-bit unsigned. Perhaps try [Copy Raster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Copy_Raster/001700000094000000/) on the scaled raster with the optional pixel_type parameter in your model to help with this.

Answer (score 3):

After running [Raster Calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000z7000000), use the [Copy Raster tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000094000000) with the `pixel_type` parameter set to `8_BIT_UNSIGNED`, as shown below.

[image]